# Pre-Launch Indexing - Is it good to posting on-topic content for indexing prior to launch?

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, launch

Is it worthwhile to put up some content, sans design, just for the purpose of getting indexed on the topic/product of the site that will be launched.

For example:

Domain = www.YourCity-FooProduct.com

Idea is to post a page or two about FooProduct, and even YourCity, perhaps the company name, phone, etc., just for the benefit of getting indexed on that topic for a longer period of time than would otherwise be achieved if there were nothing on the site until the site design and content were completed?

After launch, the content would be replaced entirely. The topic(s) remain the same, but there would be no segue to the full site.

Comment: Absolutely putting up some basic content pre-launch is far better than a site that says "Coming soon" which says nothing about your product. Getting indexed the sooner the better is always good, especially with relevant on topic content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the sooner you can get relevant related content indexed on the site the better. As we all know search engine indexing can be a bit of a black art so getting a head start with relevant content should give you an advantage when you come to launching the site fully as the search engine will already be looking for the site.

Comment: Vince, I'm late with this comment, but is it possible for you to cite a source on this? (not that I don't trust your word)